# How can we get maximum life of a water well?

Tags: water, well

If we found a water well, how can we get the life time of a water well. Is it possible, I could not found the answer on internet search.

Comment: Crosspost of https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/19900/6973

Comment: you have not found the answer on the internet, because your question makes absolutely no sense. .... nobody can predict how long any well will provide water ..... it all has to do with underground streams which can change direction at any time

Comment: @jsotola In this world everything has an expiry date... Is it make sense ? Question was quit clear

Answer (score 3):

Since you are asking about a very old well in your comment , how long can a well last? There are water wells still in use today from biblical times.
If they are deep enough and have not been contaminated by surface water or things being dumped in them the well will last as long as there is water. 
You would want to have a sample tested to make sure the water is safe to drink but if the water is good I would use it without question.

Answer (score 2):

Make an appointment with a "water well" guy and have him ascertain the  viability of the found well. He can check the pump, wiring, condition of the piping, capacity of the well and make recommendations for up-grading the well if that is what is needed.

Comment: Can any well have more than 500 years life ?